# Implications of adding work account to an android device

Tags: android, hardening, byod

Once there's a primary Google account registered on the device and then another work account is added in order to access G Suite of the work place, what are the G Suite administrators are able to access/modify on the phone?

Especially:

1. Are they able to install apps remotely?
2. Are they able to intercept communications, by registering private SSL certificates or other means?

Assuming the phone is not rooted.

Comment: AFAIK the administrators can only handle stuff *inside* the work profile. They cannot remotely install apps on your personal profile nor can they uninstall/wipe your personal data. They can however wipe remotely the work profile. They can install stuff that intercepts traffic *for the apps installed in your work profile*. At least I use the work profile and this is what Google says when you activate it and what is says about intercepting traffic. Hopefully someone else can give a more authoritative answer